# I want to write a generic function where for these valid date format MM/dd/yyyy, M/dd/yyyy or M/d/yyyy, function return true

Tags: java, validation, date

I have a flat file with below data

```
2/12/2016
2/3/2017
12/23/2017
04/23/2017
```

first is in M/dd/yyyy, second is in M/d/yyyy and rest of them having date format MM/dd/yyyy. I am using below function to check data validity for above data file.

```
public static boolean isValidDateFormat(String format, String value) 
    {
        boolean Retval = false;
        Date date = null;
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
        date = sdf.parse(value);
        if (value.equals(sdf.format(date))) {
                    Retval= true;
        }
        return Retval;
    }
```

I have to check date validity within loop and can pass only one date format like `isValidDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy", "2/12/2016")`. Above function return `false for first two values` and `true for rest of them`.

I want to write a generic function where for these valid date format MM/dd/yyyy, M/dd/yyyy or M/d/yyyy, function return true.

Comment: and what to make out of 03/04/2017? March 4th or April 3rd?

Comment: March 4.. date format is MM/dd/yyyy

Comment: ah, sorry I thought you had mixed american and europe styles

Comment: First off, you probably should use the new `java.time.format` package.

Comment: You are mentioning three possible formats. Can we rule out that any date is in MM/d/yyyy format?? How would October 5 be written??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just allow to provide to method more than one format?

```
public static boolean isValidDateFormat(String value, String... formats) 
{
    for(String format : formats) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
        Date date = sdf.parse(value);
        if(value != null && value.equals(sdf.format(date)) ) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

then you can keep your allowed formats in collection and provide it to the method

```
String[] formats = new String[]{"dd.mm.yyyy", "dd/mm/yyyy"};

if(isValidDateFormat("12.12.2014", formats) {
    //do sth
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the `java.time` API, your method could be rewritten to this

```
public static boolean isValidDateFormat(String value){
    try {
        LocalDate.parse(value, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/uuuu").withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT));
    } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

This will return `true` for MM/dd/yyyy, M/dd/yyyy, MM/d/yyyy, M/d/yyyy.

We need to specify the ResolveStyle explicitly here. Java uses `ResolverStyle.SMART` as a default. This allows you to enter days in the range of 1 - 31 for every month, and Java converts invalid days (30th of February for example) to the last valid day of the month.

We don't need that "smart" behaviour here, hence the `ResolverStyle.STRICT`.

---

This is not as neat or short, but works as well:

```
public static boolean isValidDateFormat(String value){
    String[] sa = value.split("/");
    if (sa[2].length() != 4) return false;
    try {
        LocalDate.of(Integer.parseInt(sa[2]), Integer.parseInt(sa[0]), Integer.parseInt(sa[1]));
    } catch (DateTimeException e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for but it return true for 2/30/2017 i.e 30 Feb 2017 which is not correct.

Comment: @Ajay Managed to find the flaw in my original answer and have added a second solution that works too.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to using a validation based on `SimpleDateFormat`s would be using a regex which would accept the 3 different formats :

```
value.matches("(0?\\d|1[0-2])/([0-2]?\\d|3[01])/\\d{4}")
```

I expect it to be much more efficient, however it has multiple problems :

- it does accept some invalid dates that I think would be rejected by the `SimpleDateFormat`, such as `02/31/2017`
- you should then change your method's signature since the `format` argument doesn't make sense anymore (unless you want to pass the regex there)
- it loses some meaning : regexp matches any text, while a `SimpleDateFormat` explicitly matches dates (represented as text)

Answer (score -1):

The favourable solution would be to make the date entries consistent in the flat file in the first place so that you will only have to use one DateFormat. You could perhaps write a utility to prefix any single digit month or day entries with 0s.

Alternatively, you could employ a utility method to sanity check the date before selecting a DateFormat. For example, it could split the String at the '/' character, giving you an array of Strings. You could then check the length of the first two tokens of the array to determine which Date format you need to use.

Comment: It seems to me you are solving a nonexisting problem. [Robin Topper’s answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43615206/5772882) already demonstrates how you can process all three formats with just one format object.

Comment: When I started typing my answer, no other answers had yet been submitted. Robin's suggestion is excellent, and I wouldn't have submitted this if I'd seen that first. But surely there's nothing wrong with throwing a few other ideas into the hat?

Comment: Nothing wrong with that, I agree (and it wasn’t me downvoting). Generally better to leave to the asker (and anyone else searching here for solutions to similar questions) to make their pick.