# Java - How to check if a value is of type Date

Tags: java, date

I have a project requirement. There are values in a .txt as -

```
 02/01/2017 00:00:00
```

Now I need to have some rules to check if this value in the  data file is of type Date. How can I do that? Thanks. I am new to Java so any help much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Try to parse the String to a date. If it works your string is a date.

Comment: What does the surrounding text look like? How do you store the file contents after reading it? Date or LocalDate?

Comment: Convert that string into date format object if it gets convert its date if it gives any exception its not a date

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to convert String into Date time format in JAVA?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16910344/how-to-convert-string-into-date-time-format-in-java)

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS, it’s not really that simple. With lenient parsing, invalid days will be accepted. Lenient is the default for the old `SimpleDateFormat`, fortunately not for the new `java.time` classes like `LocalDateTime`.

Comment: Even though you say `Date` (possibly referring to `java.util.Date`), I would still recommend using the `java.time` classes if you can. Look into `LocalDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: I answered [a very similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43614449/i-want-to-write-a-generic-function-where-for-these-valid-date-format-mm-dd-yyyy/43615206?noredirect=1#comment74297287_43615206) with a `java.time` api solution yesterday. The pre-Java8 version is now between the answers here

Comment: With a little search effort you should have been able to find enough similar questions to put a solution together yourself. If in that proces you get stuck, please ask a more specific question, demonstrating what you have tried and in what way it failed or was insufficient.

Comment: Example of a similar question: [How to check validity of Date String?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4010258/how-to-check-validity-of-date-string). See if you cannot use that and adopt to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Try to parse it to date. If it throws `ParseException` then it is not a date.

```
String dateString = "02/01/2017 00:00:00";
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"); 
Date date;
try {
    date = df.parse(dateString);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: According to your code `"02/31/2017 00:00:00"`is a valid date

Comment: @RobinTopper so what? its a valid US date. 9/11 is for European people the eleventh of September and is written like this `11.09.2001` but in US its `09/11/2001`

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I don't think the 31st of February should be a valid date ... regardless of your location

Answer (score 1):

If you just want valid days, use non-lenient parsing:

```
String dateString = "02/28/2017 00:00:00";

DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
df.setLenient(false);
Date date;
try {
    date = df.parse(dateString);
    System.out.println(date);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This will throw an exception for non-existing days like the 31st of February

Answer (score 1):

1. Methord 1

   ```
   Date dt = new Date(); //this should your Dynamic object

   if (dt.getClass().equals(new Date().getClass())) 
   {
     //if its date object
   }
   ```
2. Methord 2

   ```
    if(dt instanceof  Date){
      //if its date object
    }
   ```

Comment: I know the question isn’t clear, but I think it’s clear enough that the data asked about comes from a text file ( extension `.txt`). So I can’t see how your answer is relevant? Also I recommend you don’t use `Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead depending on  requirements use `LocalDateTime` or `Instant`; both are from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: I understood just now .... sorry ....you have to use only try catch method.... maybe you can create a different function and write all types of date and all formates in it ...call that function and get a boolean value return... I dont think some other option will be there

Answer (score 0):

Use this to check date

```
String sDate1="31/12/1998 00:00:00";  
try{
  Date date1=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss").parse(sDate1);  `
} 
catch(Exception e)
{
  //Not a date..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions to check the format

```
public boolean isDate(String s){
String pattern= "([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{4}) ([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})";
return s.matches(pattern);}
```

Comment: So ... `"99/99/9999 00:00:00"` would be a date?

Comment: No. This is the direction to thinking. For example, here is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491894/regex-to-validate-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy correct date recognition.

Comment: @АлексейМокрев I very much doubt that you can properly check dates with a regex, especially 29th of Feb on leap years, unless it becomes an undecipherable mess. Trying to parse the date is much cleaner in my opinion (and less error prone).

Answer (score 0):

Here’s the Java 8 solution (it can be made to work in Java 6 and 7 too when you use the ThreeTen Backport).

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter DATE_TIME_FORMAT 
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/uuuu HH:mm:ss")
                .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT);

public static boolean hasTypeDate(String stringFromTxt) {
    try {
        DATE_TIME_FORMAT.parse(stringFromTxt);
        return true;
    } catch (DateTimeParseException dtpe) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Stay away from `SimpleDateFormat` for new code. It has had its time, it’s been outdated for a while now.

If you intended the day of month first (if `02/01/2017` means January 2nd), you need the format pattern `dd/MM/uuuu HH:mm:ss` instead.

If you need to know which date and time was in the `.txt`, use:

```
        LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(stringFromTxt, DATE_TIME_FORMAT);
```

Link: [ThreeTen Backport: `java.time` classes for Java 6 and 7](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).

Answer (score -1):

```
public static boolean isValidDate(String inDate) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    dateFormat.setLenient(false);
    try {
      dateFormat.parse(inDate.trim());
    } catch (ParseException pe) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

public static void main(String[] args) {
 String file = "/path/to/your/file.txt";

try {

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file)));
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        // do something with line
    }
    br.close();
   isValidDate(line));
   //do what you want :)
  }
```

Comment: You may want to use the format the OP is asking for.